# Finding a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

How do I find a differential equation for this equation:

$ax+(y-b)^2=0$

I've tried deriving for $x$ and $y$ but it didn't work out very well.

Comment: So you want a differential equation such that the solution $y(x)$ solves the above equation?

Comment: @AlexS: I want a differential equation whose solution is the family of curves pictured above.

Comment: You have two constants $a$ and $b$, that means you need a second order differential equation... now, since you have the solution to "this" differential equation, you need to differentiate two times and replace the constants.

Comment: @raul: I've tried that, but I get a 2nd degree polynomial with $b^2$ and I don't know how to resolve for $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to get the constants by themselves, so they go away after differentiation.

Solve for $a$ and differentiate

$$ \frac{(y-b)^2}{x} = a $$
$$ \frac{2(y-b)y'x - (y-b)^2}{x^2} = 0$$
$$ 2xy' - (y-b) = 0 $$

Solve for $b$ and differentiate again

$$ 2xy' - y = b $$
$$ 2xy'' + 2y' - y' = 0 $$
$$ \boxed{2xy'' + y' = 0} $$

You can check by solving the equation
$$ \frac{y''}{y'} = -\frac{1}{2x} $$
$$ \ln{y'} = C -\frac{1}{2}\ln x $$
$$ y' = c_1x^{-1/2} $$
$$ y = c_2 + 2c_1x^{1/2} $$
$$ 4{c_1}^2x = (y-c_2)^2 $$

or $4{c_1}^2 = a$ and $c_2 = b$

Answer (score 1):

So, we start from here

$
\begin{eqnarray}
ax+(y−b)^2=0,\hspace{3cm}(1)
\end{eqnarray}
$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants and $y(x)$, then:

Taking a first implicit derivative

$
\begin{eqnarray}
 a+2y'(y-b)=0\hspace{3cm}(2)
\end{eqnarray}
$

One more derivative:

$
\begin{eqnarray}
2y''(y-b)+2(y')^2=0\hspace{3cm}(3)
\end{eqnarray}
$

From (2) we got:

$
\begin{eqnarray}
 a=-2y'(y-b)\hspace{3cm}(4)
\end{eqnarray}
$

Replacing (4) in (1) we got:

$
\begin{eqnarray}
-2y'(y-b)x+(y−b)^2=0\hspace{3cm}
\end{eqnarray}
$

If $y\neq b$ then

$
\begin{eqnarray}
-2y'x+(y−b)=0\hspace{3cm}(5)
\end{eqnarray}
$

and from here $(y-b)=2xy'$, which leaves (3) as:

$
\begin{eqnarray}
4y''xy'+2(y')^2=0\hspace{3cm}
\end{eqnarray}
$

or

$
\begin{eqnarray}
2y'(2y''x+y')=0\hspace{3cm}(6)
\end{eqnarray}
$

This is a general solution for the problem (no matter if $y=b$). When $y=b$, you have that $y'=0$ and when $y\neq b$ you have $2y''x+y'=0$.